# Extended Regular Expressions only use in “pattern”, not “replacement”?

Tags: r

To clean the text scraped from web page, I ran gsub() to replace those redundant symbols. In this proceed, I use Extended Regular Expressions(such as `[:blank:], [:digit:], [:print:]`, etc.). But they take the place of the letters which they have in the target text, and the real function they should be unfeasible in practice.

```
pg<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/1066693?mode=full&submit_simple=Show+full+item+record"
library(XML)
MetaNode <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(pg), '//table[@class="itemDisplayTable"]')
meta_label <- xpathSApply(MetaNode[[1]], './/td[@class="metadataFieldLabel"]', xmlValue)
meta_label <- gsub("[[:blank:]]+", "[:blank:]", meta_label)
meta_label <- gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", meta_label)
meta_label
```

> [1] "Titleblank"                                   [2] "Authorblank"
>   [3] "IssuedblankDateblank"                         [4] "Sourceblank"
>   [5] "IndexedblankTypeblank"                        [6]
>   "ContentblankTypeblank"                        [7] "URI标识blank"
>   [8] "OpenblankAccessblank\r\nTypeblank"            [9]
>   "fulltextblankversionblank\r\nblanktypeblank" [10] "专题blank"

1. Are those Extended Regular Expressions only use in the “pattern”
   parameter of the functions, but could not use in “replacement”?
2. And the special symbol like “\r”, “\n” have their Extended Regular
   Expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `[::blank::]` as a replacement because that stands for a whole class of different types of symbols. If you want to reduce multiple repeated characters to the first occurance, you can use something like

```
x<-"Hello    World"
gsub("([[:blank:]])+", "\\1", x)
# [1] "Hello World"
```

Here we use regular expression capture groups to grab the value that was found in the regular expression.

Comment: I tried different form of  Extended Regular Expressions and found that use different brackets may have different effects, such like () or [], one level or two([[]]). Is there any documents intruduce about this?